# DB2 Express-C 9.7.2 - consistency failure in Repeatable read

Tags: database, db2

I'm doing a DB Tuning assignment where I run swaps of balances in accounts concurrently with a sum of all balances.

My setup is that I run for instance 50 threads with 100 swaps.
The DB2 currently committed semantics is set to ON as in the default configuration.

If I iterate the experiment enough times, I end up getting a consistency error i.e. the total sum of the balances are changed. Hence I must have had some lost updates.

Lost updates should not be possible in repeatable read(?).

As far as I understand currently committed semantics works as a snapshot isolation so that if another transaction is accessing data while the original transaction is writing, it uses the currently committed data and not uncommitted writes in the concurrently running transaction. This comes at a risk of lost updates. But according to what I can find in the db2 documentation this only applies to Cursor Stability.

Now I get lost updates with Repeatable Read Isolation level. Does anyone have an idea why this is?

EDIT:

**swap1.sql:**

```
select balance from accounts where number = ? for update;
```

**swap2.sql:**

```
update accounts set balance = ? where number = ?;
```

**sum.sql:**

```
select sum(balance) from accounts;
```

**init.sql**

```
create table accounts(number integer not null primary key, branchnum integer not null, balance float not null);


#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
DB2/ValueOfSerializability/experiment.py

import sys
import getopt
import timeit
import multiprocessing
import random
import os
import ibm_db
import time


### Experiment parameters (default values)
NBRUNS         = 5          # Number of runs (-r:, --runs=)
NBSWAPS        = 100        # Number of swaps (-s:, --swaps=)
NBSWAPTHREADS  = 10         # Number of swap threads (-t:, --threads=)
RANGE_LOW      = 1          # Lower bound of the range for account number
RANGE_UP       = 1000000    # Upper bound of the range for account number
ISOL_LEVEL     = 'RR'

### Output parameters (default values)
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH  = '.'   # Path of the output file output.txt (append)

### Database parameters (DATABASE; HOSTNAME; PORT; USERNAME; PASSWORD)
sys.path.append("..")
from db2 import *

# Process Manager data structure
q = None

""""
Swapping of balance values.
read balance for account number X into valX and for account number Y into valY.
update account number X with balance set to valY
update account number Y with balance set to valX
X < Y
We avoid deadlocks because of the clustered index on
account number that garantees that account numbers
are accessed in acending order.
"""
def swap(q):
    swap1_str= q[0]; swap2_str = q[1]
    # Connect to DB
    conn = ibm_db.pconnect(DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    if conn is None: raise Usage(ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
    ibm_db.autocommit(ibm_db.SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF)
    # Set isolation level
    ret = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "SET CURRENT ISOLATION = "+ISOL_LEVEL)
    # Prepare Statements
    swap1_stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, swap1_str)
    if (swap1_stmt == False):
        raise Usage("Failed to prepare swap1 query")
    swap2_stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, swap2_str)
    if (swap2_stmt == False):
        raise Usage("Failed to prepare swap2 update")
    # Execute Statements
    nbrep = int(round(NBSWAPS / NBSWAPTHREADS))
    for i in range(nbrep):
        x = random.randint(RANGE_LOW, RANGE_UP/2)
        y = random.randint(x,RANGE_UP)
        if ibm_db.execute(swap1_stmt, (x,)) == False:
            raise Usage("Failed to execute the swap1 query (x)")
        valX = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(swap1_stmt)
        if valX == False:
            raise Usage("Failed to iterate over the swap1 result set (x)")
        if ibm_db.execute(swap1_stmt, (y,)) == False:
            raise Usage("Failed to execute the swap1 query (y)")
        valY = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(swap1_stmt)
        if valY == False:
            raise Usage("Failed to iterate over the swap1 result set (y)")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if ibm_db.execute(swap2_stmt, (valY[0],x)) == False:
            raise Usage("Failed to execute the swap2 query (x, valY)")
        if ibm_db.execute(swap2_stmt, (valX[0],y)) == False:
            raise Usage("Failed to execute the swap1 query (y, valX)")
        ibm_db.commit(conn)
    # Disconnect from DB
    status = ibm_db.close(conn)
    if status == False: raise Usage("Failed to close db connection.\n")


def summation(q):
    sum_str = q[2]
    # Connect to DB
    conn = ibm_db.pconnect(DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    if conn is None:
        raise Usage(ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
    ibm_db.autocommit(ibm_db.SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF)
    # Set isolation level
    ret = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "SET CURRENT ISOLATION = "+ISOL_LEVEL)
    # Prepare statement
    sum_stmt   = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sum_str)
    if (sum_stmt == False): raise Usage("Failed to prepare sum query")
    # Execute statement
    if ibm_db.execute(sum_stmt) == False:
        raise Usage("Failed to execute the sum query")
    sum= ibm_db.fetch_tuple(sum_stmt)
    ibm_db.commit(conn)
    # Print result set to output file
    try:
      f = open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH+'/output.txt', 'a')
      f.write(str(sum)+'\n')
      f.close()
    except IOError, e:
      raise Usage("Failed to manipulate output.txt.\n")
    finally:
      f.close()
    # Disconnect from DB
    status = ibm_db.close(conn)
    if status == False: raise Usage("Failed to close db connection.\n")

"""
Thread wrapper class
"""
class Thread(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)
        self.start()

def experiment(q):
    ThreadL = []
    # Launch swap threads
    for n in range(NBSWAPTHREADS):
        ThreadL.append(Thread(swap,q))
    # Launch Summation thread
    ThreadL.append(Thread(summation, q))
    # Barrier
    for t in ThreadL:
        t.join()

help_message = '''
python sumNswap.py [options]
options:
-h, --help       : this help message
-t, --threads=   : number of swap threads (1..59)
-s, --swaps=     : total number of swaps (< 1000)
-r, --runs=      : number of repetitions (< 100)
-i, --isol=      : isolation level ('UR', 'CS', 'RS','RR')
-o, --output=    : path to output file (result.txt)

Executes sum and swap transactions against the database described in ../db2.py
and prints timing

Example: python sumNswap.py -t10 -s1000 -r5 -iCS
'''

class Usage(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

def main(argv=None):
    global NBRUNS, NBSWAPS, NBSWAPTHREADS, RANGE_LOW, RANGE_UP, ISOL_LEVEL
    global OUTPUT_FILE_PATH
    global q
    try:
        if argv is None:
            argv = sys.argv

            try:
                opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:],
                "ho:vr:s:t:g:i:",
                ["help", "output=", "runs=","swaps=", "threads=", "isol="])
            except getopt.error, msg:
                raise Usage(msg)
    
        # Option processing
        for option, value in opts:
            if option == "-v":
                verbose = True
            if option in ("-h", "--help"):
                raise Usage(help_message)
            if option in ("-r", "--runs"):
                v = int(value)
                if not (v < 100): raise Usage("Runs out of bounds")
                NBRUNS = v
            if option in ("-s", "--swaps"):
                v = int(value)
                if not (v < 10000): raise Usage("Swaps out of bounds")
                NBSWAPS = v
            if option in ("-t", "--threads"):
                v = int(value)
                if (v < 0 or v>60): raise Usage("Threads out of bounds")
                NBSWAPTHREADS = v
            if option in ("-i", "--isol"):
                if not value in ['UR', 'CS', 'RS', 'RR']: raise Usage("Isolation level not supported")
                ISOL_LEVEL = value
            if option in ("-o", "--output"):
                if not os.path.exists(value): raise Usage("Result file path does not exist")
                OUTPUT_FILE_PATH= value
    
        # Verify preconditions: required sql files exist
        try:
            f = open('sum.sql', 'r')
            sum_str = f.readline()
            f.close()
        except IOError, e:
            raise Usage("Failed to manipulate sum.sql.\n")
    
        try:
            f = open('swap1.sql', 'r')
            swap1_str = f.readline()
            f.close()
        except IOError, e:
            raise Usage("Failed to manipulate swap1.sql.\n")
    
        try:
            f = open('swap2.sql', 'r')
            swap2_str = f.readline()
            f.close()
        except IOError, e:
            raise Usage("Failed to manipulate swap2.sql.\n")
    
        print 'run (isol: '+ISOL_LEVEL+', threads: '+str(NBSWAPTHREADS)+', swaps:'+str(NBSWAPS)+')'
        # Queue Initialization
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        q = manager.list([swap1_str, swap2_str, sum_str])
    
        # Timed experiment
        t = timeit.Timer("experiment(q)", "from __main__ import experiment,q")
        timings = []
        try:
            # repeat 1 experiment NBRUNS time - output is a list of timing
            timings = t.repeat(NBRUNS,1)
            # Log timing
            for timing in timings:
                s = str(timing)
                print s        
        except: 
            raise Usage(t.print_exc())
            
    except Usage, err:
        print >> sys.stderr, sys.argv[0].split("/")[-1] + ": " + str(err.msg)
        print >> sys.stderr, "\t for help use --help"
        return 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Please post some detail about what each thread is doing (code or specific SQL statements at a minimum) , and what the transaction scope is (i.e. when is a commit done).

Comment: Sorry about that, Ian.
I guess it must be a bug in the script. It makes no sense that I should have any inconsistency using RR or CS for that matter.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde
Sorry about that, Ian.
I guess it must be a bug in the script. It makes no sense that I should have any inconsistency using RR or CS for that matter.
I run the experiment with 100 swaps, 50 runs and with 1, 5, 10, 25 and 50 threads respectively.
It seems that the isolation level is set correctly in the script. I must admit though, that neither db2 or python is my native language.

Answer (score 3):

Actually CURRENTLY COMMITTED is a property of CURSOR STABILITY isolation.
All CC does is to get the currently committed version of a row whenever it runs into a lock instead of "wait for outcome" which has been DB2's traditional behavior.

REPEATABLE READ is a different isolation level.

If there is any DB2 documentation equating CURRENTLY COMMITTED to REPEATABLE READ please point me to it so I can get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks. That is also what I thought. I was just a little bit vary of whether CURRENTLY COMMITTED was relevant for REPEATABLE READ as well. 
Then my problem is still unresolved. I simply don't understand how I can get lost updates with Repeatable Read isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

I think that lost updates are possible in the following scenario for repeatable read:

in the scenario with isolation level set to RR:

1) transaction t1 reads data from row r1,

2) transaction t2 reads same data from row r1 (because read lock is shared),

3) t1 modifies the data read in #1 and commits data to r1 (it update shared read lock to exclusive write lock, and releases it once committed)

4) t2 modifies the data read in #2 and commits data to r1 (lock sequence similar as above)- t1's update is lost.

I guess one solution to this issue is using versioning and detecting updates and then retrying the transaction.